# Other uses of "imperative prohibition" form eg わかるな　・すわんな

Tags: grammar, meaning, imperatives

I saw a film where in two separate scenes the characters seemed to use the "imperative-prohibition" to invite the opposite action:

> 1.In one scene a father after explaining something to his son appeared to ask his son if he could understand what he had explained:
>
> 「わかるな」？
>
> It was as if he had said: 「[おれのいうこと]、分かりませんか」？
>
> 2.In another scene a woman invited a child to sit on a chair that she was pointing at:
>
> 「すわんな」
>
> As if she had said: 「座りませんか」

In both cases I am sure I have quoted the subtitles correctly but is this really the imperative prohibition or have I missed something?

Comment: Those have different accent/intonation patters from the imperative prohibition (at least in the Tokyo dialect).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in that context, that `わかるな？` uses sense 3 of [this entry](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AA&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&index=114424700000&pagenum=11) at Daijirin to "seek agreement or a response". It might be similar to `わかるよね？` ("you understand, right?")

I think `すわんな` would be a more colloquial form of `座りな`/`座りなさい` "sit down". I think `な` here is a shortened form of `なさい` to make a command as in [this entry](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AA&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&index=114424900000&pagenum=11). Note this is different from the prohibitional `座るな` "don't sit".

Comment: To summarise: neither one is the prohibitional な.

Comment: how common is this construct? I've never heard it before...

Comment: Because both are considered rude.

Comment: ＠Gradius: But apparently ok to use with children (which does not sound strange).

Comment: @Tim You can use the expressions to children (or intimate friends), but the children don't (shouldn't) use them to adults, even to their parents. It means the expressions sound rude.